# Close JqueryUI dialog from inside an asp.net mvc partial view form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following partial view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditUserRole", "Administrator", null, new AjaxOptions{ OnSuccess = "CloseWnd()"))
{
    <input type="submit" class="jqBtn" />
}
```

I get this by ajax and insert it into a dialog like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "GetEditUserRoleControl", new { userId = x.UserId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "WndContent", OnSuccess="OpenWnd('Edit User Roles')" }, new { @class = "ui-icon ui-icon-person BtnIcon" })

<div id="WndContent" style="display: none;">

</div>

<script>
function OpenWnd(title) {
   var $dialog = $("#WndContent").dialog({ title: title, modal: true });
   //get the widget element
   var $widg = $dialog.dialog('widget');
   //find all buttons and apply button:
   $("input:submit.jqBtn", $widg).button();

}
</script>
```

I need after I submit the form, I close the box. But it seems I'll be writing code in the partial control that depends on the dialog. I also do not want to use the built in jquery buttons because I'll have to remove the button from my partial form. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could look in the content for a form, and bind to the submit function.

```
$("form", $widg).submit(function(){
    /* submit callback */
});
```

This will tell you when the form is submitted however, not when the ajax submit status.

My suggestion would be to use the `dialog` buttons (since that is how this dialog is designed to be used) and modify your view to optionally render the buttons. You could pass another key `modalView=true` through the action link.